# creating table from data in R

Tags: r

I want to create a table from the existing data. I have 5 varieties and 3 clusters in the data. In the expected table I want to show the number and the name of the varieties with the corresponding clusters. But I cannot make it. This is my data

```
variety<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
cluster<-c(1,2,2,3,1)
x <- cbind(variety, cluster)
data <- data.frame(x)
data

    variety cluster
1       a       1
2       b       2
3       c       2
4       d       3
5       e       1
```

My desirable table is like this.

```
cluster    number   variety name

1            2       a, e
2            2       b,c
3            1       d
```

I would be grateful if anyone helps me.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(cluster) %>% summarise(number = n(), variety_name = toString(variety))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can give the results you're looking for:

```
library(plyr)
variety<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
cluster<-c(1,2,2,3,1)
x <- cbind(variety, cluster)
data <- data.frame(x)
data

ddply(data,.(cluster),summarise,n=length(variety),group=paste(variety,collapse=','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  Grouped by 'cluster', get the number of rows (`n()`) and `paste` the 'variety' into a single string (`toString`)

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarise(number = n(), variety_name = toString(variety))
```